# Бесконечная бегущая строка @keyframes

Tags: css

Коллеги, добрый вечер.
Нашел массу вопрос на эту тему, но применение решений, что предлагаются мне не помогают.
Задача сделать непрерывную бегущую строку. Собственно она у меня получилась и все работает. Но как всегда есть одно "НО".
Когда итерация заканчивается - строка одергивается и начинает следующую.

```css
.ticker__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    animation: ticker 5s linear infinite;
}

ticker__item {
      padding: 15px 30px;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #f7f7f7;
   }

@keyframes ticker {
   0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
   }

   100% {
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker">
    <ul class="ticker__wrapper">
        <li class="ticker__item">0</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">1</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">2</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">3</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">4</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">5</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">6</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">7</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">8</li>
        <li class="ticker__item">9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: можно сдвинуть стартовую точку за правую границу экрана, так "одергивание" "спрячется".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось так: добавил еще элементов списка. Если у кого-то есть более элегантное решение, напишите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="ticker">
    <ul class="ticker__wrapper">
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
        <li class="ticker__item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width:500px;
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

a {
    color: #121212;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 130px;
}

.ticker-list li {
    line-height: 130px;
}

.ticker-list {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;

    -webkit-animation: pooja 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: pooja 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: pooja 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    -o-animation: pooja 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: pooja 20s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes "pooja" {
 0% {
    margin-top: 0;
 }
 25% {
    margin-top: -180px;
 }
 50% {
    margin-top: -340px;
 }
 75% {
    margin-top: -510px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-top: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes pooja {
 0% {
   margin-top: 0;
 }
 25% {
   margin-top: -180px;
 }
 50% {
   margin-top: -340px;
 }
 75% {
   margin-top: -510px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-top: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "pooja" {
 0% {
   margin-top: 0;
 }
 25% {
   margin-top: -180px;
 }
 50% {
   margin-top: -340px;
 }
 75% {
   margin-top: -510px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-top: 0;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "pooja" {
    0%  {
     margin-top: 0;
}
 25% {
   margin-top: -180px;
 }
 50% {
   margin-top: -340px;
 }
 75% {
   margin-top: -510px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-top: 0;
 }

}

 @-o-keyframes "pooja" {
    0%  {
     margin-top: 0;
}
 25% {
    margin-top: -180px;
 }
 50% {
    margin-top: -340px;
 }
 75% {
    margin-top: -510px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="ticker-list">
          <li><a href="#">fun</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">laugh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Есть такое, например. Если переписать margin-top, то и анимация будет быстрее или медленнее, соответственно или если добавить другое позиционирование

Comment: а зачем прфиксы для keyframes? Разве по стандарту они не работают во всех браузерах?

Comment: Ну, кстати, да. Опера, например, уже не отстает от основных браузеров (и многие браузеры), но при этом сейчас, как мне кажется, появилось намного больше технологий, библиотек и фреймворков. Часто забывают про кроссбраузерность, а анимации должны везде вроде работать, на всех площадках.

Comment: А здесь нельзя другому пользователю ответить? Чтобы было понятно кому я пишу

Answer (score 0):

Можно через `opacity: 0;` и возврат на исходную позицию.

```css
.ticker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ticker__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
}

ticker__item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {        
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }    
  99% {    
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 }
 100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 }   
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker">
  <ul class="ticker__wrapper">
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
    <li class="ticker__item">PAYMENTS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```