# Бегущая строка моргает при повторном запуске

Tags: css, css-animation

Коллеги, добрый день.
Реализована бегущая строка:

```css
.ticker {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #202020;
}
.ticker__wrapper {
    padding: 12px 0;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ticker__text {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: ticker 18s linear infinite;
}
.ticker__item {
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
@keyframes ticker {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker">
    <div class="ticker__wrapper">
        <div class="ticker__text">
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ticker__wrapper">
        <div class="ticker__text">
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Все работает - движение происходит непрерывно. Но, когда keyframes доходит до 100% - начинает новую итерацию - анимация моргает.
Подскажите, как я могу это исправить.

Спасибо

Comment: Очень просто, у вас от 0 до 100% стоит итерация, а должна вернуться к нулю и потом начаться от нуля опять. Просто между 0 и 100% создайте 50% и там напишите transform: translateX(-100%);, а в 100% напишите опять - transform: translateX(0);. Но из-за того, что он делает это теперь в два раза быстрее, вам нужно увеличить время анимации вдвое.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи попробовал сделать, как вы написали. Теперь, когда строка доходит до конца, она отталкивается и движется в обратную сторону.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи сейчас обратил внимание, что проблема эта есть только в мобильной версии сайта.

Comment: Если нужна непрерывная повторяющая строка, то нужен скрипт (пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668893/270124). Если только повторяющая, то смотрите предыдущий ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545602/270124

Comment: @Kniham к сожалению проблема не решилась. В мобильной версии продолжает моргать. Поменял разметку и стили (указал в теле вопроса).  Решить вопрос этот хочу с помощью css только. Вы не знаете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @ElJeko, попробуйте добавить Префиксы браузеров к `transforms` и другим

Comment: @Kniham не помогает. Буду использовать JS

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ticker {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #202020;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ticker__wrapper {
    padding: 12px 0;
    display: flex;
    animation: ticker 18s linear infinite;
}
.ticker__text {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ticker__item {
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
@keyframes ticker {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker">
    <div class="ticker__wrapper">
        <div class="ticker__text">
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 1</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 2</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 3</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 4</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 5</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 6</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 7</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ticker__wrapper">
        <div class="ticker__text">
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 1</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 2</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 3</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 4</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 5</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 6</span>
            <span class="ticker__item">Text 7</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

вот

Comment: Тоже не то. Спасибо за попытку.